# Get public IP of EC2 spot instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I try to get public IP of an EC2 spot instance, but can not find a solution for this. Exists a solution how to get this IP, from an EC2 instance (but not from a spot instance).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-ec2-elastic-ip.html

Could someone help me, please, to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing this from the instance.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Comment: But I need to do this programmatically from the java. There is a way to do it? Because, I launch from the java application, this spot instances.

Comment: Thanks in any case, because at least, at SO level we could find this information.